# Possible Date assignment error ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I'm getting the error ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected, which I think is because the date assignment in my code isn't correct. Can someone have a look at my code snippet below and let me known the correct way of assigning the date if it's wrong please?

```
     Declare

        v_task_start DATE;   
        v_task_completion DATE;  
        v_prj_start DATE;
        v_prj_completion DATE;
        l_start_date DATE;
        l_completion_date DATE;
        v_task_id NUMBER;
        v_prj_id  NUMBER;

        CURSOR c_tasks_to_update IS
            SELECT 
            pt.TASK_ID, 
            pt.Project_id AS Task_Prj_Id, 
            pt.start_date  AS Task_start,
            pt.Completion_date AS Task_Completion,
            ppa.start_date AS Project_start,
            ppa.completion_date AS Project_completion
            INTO
            v_task_id, v_prj_id, v_task_start, v_task_completion, v_prj_start, v_prj_completion
            FROM pa_tasks pt, pa_projects_all ppa
            WHERE pt.project_id = ppa.project_id
            AND pt.created_by = 1623
            and to_date(pt.creation_date,'DD-MON-YY') = to_date('26-SEP-2014', 'DD-MON-YY');

     BEGIN



          FOR ctask_update in c_tasks_to_update
          LOOP

              v_task_start          := ctask_update.Task_start;
              v_task_completion     := ctask_update.Task_Completion;
              v_prj_start           := ctask_update.Project_start;
              v_prj_completion      := ctask_update.Project_completion;

              IF ((v_task_start <> v_prj_start) and (v_task_completion <> v_prj_completion))
              THEN
               DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'Task Start date is not equal to Project start date, 
               Task completion date is not equal to Project completion date '
                ||v_task_start||' '||v_prj_start||' '||v_task_completion ||' '||   
                  v_prj_completion);

                l_start_date := to_date(trunc(v_prj_start),'DD_MON_YY');

                /*SELECT START_DATE FROM PA_PROJECTS_ALL
                      INTO l_start_date
                   FROM pa_projects_all WHERE project_id = v_prj_id;*/


                l_completion_date := to_date('trunc(v_prj_completion)','DD_MON_YY');

                /*SELECT completion_date FROM PA_PROJECTS_ALL
                  INTO l_completion_date
                  FROM pa_projects_all WHERE project_id = v_prj_id;*/

                  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'Task start date to be updated to '||
                    to_char(l_start_date));
                  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'Task completion date to be updated to '||  
                    to_char(l_completion_date));

    End;
```

I don't get to see the output statements `Task start date to be updated to:xxxx`. So the exception is occurring here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues I can see here.  Firstly, the following line:

```
and to_date(pt.creation_date,'DD-MON-YY') = to_date('26-SEP-2014', 'DD-MON-YY');
```

What is the type of `pt.creation_date`?  `CHAR`, `VARCHAR2` or `DATE`?

Don't use `CHAR` or `VARCHAR2` columns for dates as otherwise all sorts of other junk could end up in your date column: for example `31-SEP-14`, `tomorrow`, `n/a`, `asdf`, all of which will cause problems later on during processing.  Your error may be caused by dirty data in this column.

If `pt.creation_date` is a `DATE`, there is no need to call `to_date` on it, as that will force Oracle to convert the date to a string and then back to a date.  This is unnecessary.

Also, `to_date('26-SEP-2014', 'DD-MON-YY')` isn't entirely correct as you are using a four-digit year `2014` in your date string and a two-digit year `YY` in your date format picture.  However, although this looks odd, Oracle doesn't seem to have a problem with it.

The next problem is here:

```
l_start_date := to_date(trunc(v_prj_start),'DD_MON_YY');
```

`v_prj_start` is already a `DATE`, so there's no need to convert it to a date.  You are doing an unnecessary conversion from date to string and back again.  It is probably sufficient to just write

```
l_start_date := trunc(v_prj_start);
```

Also I'm not sure why you are using underscores in your date format picture (`'DD_MON_YY'`).

The next problem I see is this line:

```
l_completion_date := to_date('trunc(v_prj_completion)','DD_MON_YY');
```

This could well be the line that is generating your error.  In fact, it is guaranteed to fail with exactly the error message you report.  This is because the string `'trunc(v_prj_completion)'` isn't a valid date in the format you specified.  Oracle is expecting a number at the start of your date string and you have given it the letter `t` instead.  I imagine you intended to write the following line instead:

```
 l_completion_date := to_date(trunc(v_prj_completion),'DD_MON_YY');
```

However, once again, don't use `to_date` on a `DATE` value, so

```
 l_completion_date := trunc(v_prj_completion);
```

may well be enough.

Further on down there are two lines similar to the following:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'Task start date to be updated to '||
                    to_char(l_start_date));
```

Always use `to_char` with a date format picture, e.g. `to_char(l_start_date, 'DD-MON-YY')`.

Finally, as a general point, use four-digit years (`YYYY`) instead of two-digit years where possible.  A 2-digit year `14` will be interpreted as 2014, and `15` as 2015, but how much further can you go before 2-digit years start being interpreted as in the last century?  Perhaps `50` will be interpreted as 1950?

Comment: Luke, Thanks very much for pointing out the errors. 1) pt.creation_date is DATE, So I changed it to pt.creation_date = to_date('26-SEP-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY');

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess:

As I've noticed you use [`TO_DATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm) in your query to convert `pt.creation_date` to a proper date value, I could assume that *maybe* other date are stored as string in your table as well (which is a *bad idea™*).

So I would try something like that:

```
v_task_start          := TO_DATE(ctask_update.Task_start,'DD-MON-YY');
v_task_completion     := TO_DATE(ctask_update.Task_Completion,'DD-MON-YY');
v_prj_start           := TO_DATE(ctask_update.Project_start,'DD-MON-YY');
v_prj_completion      := TO_DATE(ctask_update.Project_completion,'DD-MON-YY');
```

Comment: Luke, 
Thanks very much for pointing out the errors
1) pt.creation_date is DATE, So I changed it to pt.creation_date = to_date('26-SEP-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY'); 
2) corrected the date formats to ('DD-MON-YYYY'). 
3) Made the assignment statement l_start_date := trunc(v_prj_start); and l_completion_date := trunc(v_prj_completion); 
4) Changed the output line to DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'Task start date to be updated to '|| to_char(l_start_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY'));
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'Task completion date to be updated to '|| to_char(l_completion_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY));.

Comment: When I run it now, it doesn't show any errors, all it displays is 'anonymous block completed' and nothing happens.

The dates are not updated as I expected them to. No output messages ( though I have run SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;) The underlying table is not updated as I would expect. What am I missing?

Comment: I resolved the last issue too. It was because the cursor was not fetching anything. Once I changed the date condition on the cursor to >  25-SEP-2014, I was able to get the outcome I wanted.

Comment: Sylvain, Thanks for your comments but as Luke pointed out That is not required as the variables are already defined as Date type.